# YouTube player API does not work with IE10 and Android?

Tags: android, iframe, youtube-api

Good time passed since the relevant posts - 2 years. I wonder if the mistake is on my part - I am using this tutorial

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?csw=1

"Getting started section".

I very enjoy the player itself which works perfectly on Firefox 23.0.1 and Chrome 29.0.1547.62 m, but it freezes in IE10 and on my Android Galaxy Nexus phone 4.3.

In IE10 it seems to freeze on the player state change. I've also tried Firefox app on my phone and again it works while native browser freezes on the same player state change.

I've checked the spec and it seems HTML5 player is supported by both IE past 8 and Android.

Could anyone enlighten me please whether the mistake is on my part or something is fundamentally wrong with IE and my Android phone native browser?

Comment: IS your IE react same on other site. It should work. post some screenshot or more info to check this Issue.

Comment: Do you generate Iframe with iframe tag or through Javascript. Maybe their is some security enable for Iframe in IE10. Try another way. change the compatibility mode and test if other way it's worked.

Comment: Yes I generate iframe with video tag like <div id="video> gets replaced with iframe. I noticed that freezing in IE is not permanent and only happens on localhost(works well in cloud). However android issue seems to happen on player state change like whenver I explicitly call playVideo() stopVideo() etc. it works ok whenever I just load the player and then use youtube native controls for playback control(no state change). Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. When I open same page with Android Chrome, video is loading successfully. But Built-in android browser and also Lumia's browser(IE) can't load video.

That's a strange situation that video can be load at Youtube player's demo page(https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo) on Android's native browser.